# "Virtual Path Not Known" When running ASP.NET MVC Unit Test Project!

Tags: asp.net-mvc, unit-testing, resources, nunit, virtual-path

Does anyone know why is it not possible to get the virtualpath when you are running the
asp.net mvc unit test project? Is it because it creates a Temp folders under TestResults Folder.??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Where would it come from with no web server running?

You have to mock anything related to paths in your mock HttpContext, e.g.:

```
request.Expect(req => req.AppRelativeCurrentExecutionFilePath).Returns("~/");
response.Expect(res => res.ApplyAppPathModifier(It.IsAny<string>()))
     .Returns((string virtualPath) => virtualPath);
```

Comment: Well the thing is when testing the controller ,from the controller i get some of the values from the global resources and i get an error "The application relative virtual path '~/' is not allowed". Is there any way to resolve this, other than having the global and local resources separated from the mvc project.